# Adapter using "IN"

Tags: c#, adapter

I have an adapter in c# and I want to know if a value (type of int) is in a list of values. How can I do it? when I do `send IN @sendList` it's giving me an error. I tried to use `LIKE` like this `@sendList LIKE '%'+ send +'%'` but Adapter can't convert from int to varchar...

Comment: Please specify the error and add some code that explain how you tried to fetch this query.

Comment: The `IN` clause requires your values to be 1. comma separated and 2. enclosed in parentheses like so `IN (1,4,6,9)`

Comment: but can't i get the list as parameter? @HuBeZa, i wrote how i tried to fetch. the error is that it can't do @sendList LIKE '%'+ send +'%' becuse "send" is an int

Comment: @sharon You cannot. you need to build the in clause yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause has many suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be splitting your list of IDs:

```
...
string.Format("Send IN {0}", string.Join(sendList.Select(id => id.ToString()));
```

But if you insist on a parameter, you can write an SQL function that convert your list to string. You can find many examples ([like this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/convert-a-string-array-to-tabular-data-in-sql-server/375)) [over the web](http://www.google.com/#q=sql+string+to+int+array).

Comment: you can still use parameters, you just need to build an in clause with as many `?`  as elements in your list -  `in (?,?,?,?,?)` and loop through the list and assign parameters